# Loop through multidimensional hash of Array and objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actually trying to access the values of multidimensional hash, which looks like this

```
{
 "page_1"=>[
     {:price=>"40 €", :price_per_day=>"40 €", :provider1=>"XX"}, 
     {:price=>"43 €", :price_per_day=>"43 €", :provider1=>"XX"}
   ],
  "page_2"=>[
     {:price=>"40 €", :price_per_day=>"40 €", :provider1=>"XX"}, 
     {:price=>"43 €", :price_per_day=>"43 €", :provider1=>"XX"}
   ]
 }
```

For example how can I get the :price inside each page_x using a loop?

Comment: It might help to know exactly what you want to do with the prices. In the first answer below you can see how to use a nested loop to access all of the prices within each page, however if you're doing any computations or collations on them, there may be a better answer we could provide ... It's always best to explain in detail what you're trying to achieve rather than just asking what you *think* you need.

Comment: I agree with Jon, if you provide an explanation stating your problem and what you're exactly trying to do then you can receive much better answer than what I presented below.

Comment: No not for computation work, Im just using capybara to crawl some datas from a website for statistics purpose. So the whole purpose of my code is to crawl and add it to a CSV file( thats were I got stuck with this multidimensional hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pages = {
 "page_1"=>[
     {:price=>"40 €", :price_per_day=>"40 €", :provider1=>"XX"}, 
     {:price=>"43 €", :price_per_day=>"43 €", :provider1=>"XX"}
   ],
  "page_2"=>[
     {:price=>"40 €", :price_per_day=>"40 €", :provider1=>"XX"}, 
     {:price=>"43 €", :price_per_day=>"43 €", :provider1=>"XX"}
   ]
 }

pages.each do |page, prices_array|
  puts page #=> "page_1", and "page_2" on the next iteration
  prices_array.each do |price|
    puts price[:price]
    puts price[:price_per_day]
    puts price[:provider1]
  end
end
```

Here in [`each do |page, prices_array|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), `page` is the `key` and `prices_array` is the `value` of hash on each iteration. Since `value` is an array, we will have to do another `each` for iterating values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the price, you can do like this:

```
   hash.values.flatten.map{ |e| e[:price] }
    => ["40 €", "43 €", "40 €", "43 €"]
```

Comment: I'll stick with surya's solution, beacause I need all informations from the hash. Even though thank you for the answer

Comment: I agree with you, if you need all information, surya's solution is better.